# Re-use large chunks of jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out how to re-use large chunks of code.

I thought it would be like this:

```
function bulkCode() {
    ... large amount of code
}

$(document).on('click', function() {
    ...blah...

    bulkCode();
});
```

I have a selection of code I want to use over three different areas, and I am sure there is a way to re use the code without pasting it in each one...

Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: what's wrong with the snippet of code you have above?

Comment: It doesn't work. Do you mean to say it should?

Comment: works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/83sPP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use your local variables:

```
var urlHead = '/portfolio/embed-head-view/'+entry+'/'+category;
var urlImage = '/portfolio/embed-image-view/'+entry+'/'+category;
var urlDetails = '/portfolio/embed-details-view/'+entry+'/'+category;
```

you have to define your function as:

```
function imageLoad(urlHead, urlImage, urlDetails){ ... }
```

and call it by passing the parameters:

```
imageLoad(urlHead, urlImage, urlDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, put the bulkCode() in a separate .js file and use a  link to us it in any page you want to use.
Why do you ask? Is the above code not working?

Comment: No, perhaps its my actual code then. I have added my code in my question. Could you take a look and see if you can see why it isn;t working?

Comment: Check the preceding lines of code before the function call. I'm sure there's a JS error some where and the function call actually never gets hit. Or perhaps, put the function call at the top (just for testing) and see if it gets called?!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the code in a .js file and include it in the page with a script tag like the following.

```
<script src="path/jsFile.js"></script>
```